# Calling Specific Child

Tags: actionscript-3

I am making a small program which shows pins on a map . The information about the pin comes from XML file including price. When a price button is clicked, lets say $900, only the pin with 900 needs to enlarge. All the pins are store inside a pinContainer_mc (blank container to put all the pins)

Pin heretics pin class which has enlarge method.

```
package bin
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class pin extends MovieClip
    {
        var thisHeight:int;
        var thisWidth:int;

        public function pin() 
        {
            thisHeight = this.height;
            thisWidth = this.width;
        }

        public function enlarge():void
        {
            this.height = thisHeight *2;
            this.width = thisWidth *2;
        }

        public function regular():void
        {
            this.height = thisHeight;
            this.width = thisWidth;
        }
    }   
}
```

Main FLA has the following:

```
// Parsing and displaying pins

for(var i:int = 0; i< myXmlList.length(); i++)
{
    pin_mc = new mcPin();
    pinContainer_mc.addChild(pin_mc);

    pin_mc.x = myXml.Community[i].xAxis;
    pin_mc.y = myXml.Community[i].yAxis;

    pin_mc.name = myXml.Community[i].Name;
    pin_mc.price = myXml.Community[i].Price;

}
```

When button is clicked:

```
rangeA_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, enlargePins);

function enlargePins(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    for(var i:int =0; i<pinConatiner_mc.numChildren;i++)
    {
        if(pinContainer_mc.getChildAt(i).price == 900)
        {
            pinContainer_mc.getChildAt(i).enlarge();
        }
    }
}
```

It gives compile error:
`Access of possibly undefined property price through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject`.

Answer (score 0):

`getChildAt` returns a DisplayObject, which does not have a price property.

If you are sure that all the children you have added to pinContainer_mc (as it appears you have), you can cast the return value to a `pin` to fix this problem.

Change your code to this:

```
if(pin(pinContainer_mc.getChildAt(i)).price == 900)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response but when I compile with

    if(pin(pinContainer_mc.getChildAt(i)).price == 900)
1180: Call to a possibly undefined method pin.

and when with 
    if(pin_mc(pinContainer_mc.getChildAt(i)).price == 900)
1180: Call to a possibly undefined method pin_mc.

Thank you,re

Comment: You need to import your pin class.  Try adding `import bin.pin;` at the top of your file.  `pin_mc` does not work because your class is named `pin` not `pic_mc` as well as it not being imported.

Comment: Thanks again, the new error says:

1119: Access of possibly undefined property price through a reference with static type bin:pin.

One thing that I didn't mentioned earlier is that I 
var pinContainer_mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip(); // Blank    MovieClip to insert pin in the map.
mapVector_mc.addChild(pinContainer_mc);

Should I just push all the pins in an array and work that way?

Comment: Hi Alan,

Just wanted to say thanks for the info. I push the pins and an array and called it from there and worked like a charm. Might not be the best way to do it but gets the work done.

Comment: @rex, that is pretty much the best way to do it. Although instead of using an Array I would use a Vector datatype, as it can make error checking easier and it is faster than Array.